# Infrared images segmentation using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, infrared

Let's say I have a series of infrared pictures and the task is to isolate human body from other objects in the picture. The problem is a noise from other relatively hot objects like lamps and their 'hot' shades.

Simple thresholding methods like binary and/or Otsu didn't give good results on difficult (noisy) pictures, so I've decided to do it manually.

[Here are some samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCAnR.jpg)

The results are not terrible, but I think they can be improved. Here I simple select pixels by hue value of HSV. More or less, hot pixels are located in this area: hue < 50, hue > 300. My main concern here is these pink pixels which sometimes are noise from lamps but sometimes are parts of human body, so I can't simply discard them without causing significant damage to the results: e.g. on the left picture this will 'destroy' half of the left hand and so on.
As the last resort I could use some strong filtering and erosion but I still believe there's a way somehow to told to OpenCV: hey, I don't need these pink areas unless they are part of a large hot cluster.
Any ideas, keywords, techniques, good articles? Thank in advance

Comment: Your sample pictures look like they have some pretty clear edges in them. Have you tried getting the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator)? You could then identify connected components and decided which ones don't look human.

Answer (score 0):

FIR data is presumably monotonically proportional (if not linear) to temperature, and this should yield a grayscale image.
Your examples are colorized with a color map - the color only conveys a single channel of actual information. It would be best if you could work directly on the grayscale image (maybe remap the images to grayscale).

Then, see if you can linearize the images to an actual temperature scale such that the pixel value represents the temperature. Once you do this you can should be able to clamp your image to the temperature range that you expect a person to appear in. Check the datasheets of your camera/imager for the conversion formula.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had similar thoughts. But anyway, let's suppose I have a grayscale image, it is still possible to have areas with the same intensity as a part of a human body as well as the part of something else - unless a man is completely naked. Am I wrong? So I would try to get rid of gray noise instead of pink. So I would like to try to solve the more general problem - how to distinguish areas which are part of a human figure from other areas with the same intensity. Do I want too much? :)

Comment: Well, once you can narrow the temperature range you're left with pretty good segmentation. You can use ML methods for classification, use geometric cues such a perspective etc.